# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware pp.middleware: "No module named pp.middleware"

Tags: python, django

im new to django and python , im trying to do runserver on a piece of django code and im running into the following problems,

```
Kinnovates-MacBook-Pro:platformsite Kinnovate$ python manage.py runserver
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4b1, using settings 'platformsite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware pp.middleware: "No module named pp.middleware"
```

im running python2.7 1.4b Django on a macOSX10.7
how do i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a middleware class specified in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` that Django is trying to import, yet it isn't available on your Python path.

You should make sure that you have obtained the middleware sources and that your Python path is properly configured.

Comment: is the problem in my code? or the django version that i have?

Comment: the problem seems to be in your settings.py

Comment: Django is, basically, trying to do `from pp.middleware import PaginationMiddleware` and failing. You need to update the path to the middleware class to make it work.

Comment: ok i have changed the pp.middleware.PaginationMiddleware to pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware.. and i managed to get it to work. thanks all!